# The network adapter sometimes stops working until the next reboot. Honor MagicBook 15 2021

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Honor MagicBook 15 BMH-WFQ9HN.

The network adapter may randomly disconnect. It is not possible to enable it via the `ip link set up` command, it gives the following error:

```
sudo ip link set wlp1s0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
```

When I tried to find information about this error, I didn't find anything even approximately similar to my problem :(

Rebooting helps, but it's terribly inconvenient. Kubuntu Info Center gives me the following information about the adapter:

```
01:00:0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e0ca
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 78, IOMMU group 7
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Managment version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count 32/32 Maskable+ 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [148] Secondary PCI Express
        Capabilities: [158] Transaction Processing Hints
        Capabilities: [1e4] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [1ec] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: ath11k_pci
        Kernel modules: ath11k_pci
```

Driver was installed automatically when the system was installed

---

**UPD 13.02.2023:**
So it happened again. What else I noticed. The adapter can disconnect itself only when connected to a 2.4GHz Wi-Fi, everything works stably with 5 GHz. Next, I guessed to get into the system logs, and that's what it says there:

First message:

```
13.02.2023 13:17    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: firmware crashed: MHI_CB_SYS_ERROR
```

Second messgae. It was repeated several hundred times:

```
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to transmit frame -108
```

And next:

```
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to queue management frame -108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to send WMI_VDEV_INSTALL_KEY cmd
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: ath11k_install_key failed (-108)
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  wlp1s0: failed to remove key (0, 54:a0:50:b3:a7:20) from hardware (-108)
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to send WMI_PEER_DELETE cmd
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to delete peer vdev_id 0 addr 54:a0:50:b3:a7:20 ret -108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Failed to delete peer: 54:a0:50:b3:a7:20 for VDEV: 0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: Found peer entry 38:d5:7a:4b:f2:a5 n vdev 0 after it was supposedly removed
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ------------[ cut here ]------------
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 810 at net/mac80211/sta_info.c:1090 __sta_info_destroy_part2+0x172/0x1a0 [mac80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  Modules linked in: ccm michael_mic rfcomm vboxnetadp(O) vboxnetflt(O) qrtr_mhi vboxdrv(O) cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep intel_rapl_msr joydev intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_generic edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep qrtr ns uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_v4l2 btusb kvm_amd ath11k_pci btrtl binfmt_misc snd_rawmidi input_leds snd_pci_acp6x videobuf2_common ath11k kvm btbcm qmi_helpers btintel huawei_wmi snd_pcm mac80211 bluetooth videodev snd_seq nls_iso8859_1 rapl ecdh_generic ledtrig_audio mc ecc hid_multitouch snd_seq_device sparse_keymap wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_pci_acp5x snd_timer cfg80211 k10temp libarc4 snd snd_rn_pci_acp3x mhi snd_pci_acp3x soundcore ccp mac_hid amd_pmc sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops pstore_blk reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ib_uverbs ib_core
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   amdgpu(O) amddrm_ttm_helper(O) amdttm(O) iommu_v2 amd_sched(O) amdkcl(O) i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops cec hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel rc_core xhci_pci aesni_intel i2c_hid_acpi nvme i2c_hid crypto_simd cryptd drm i2c_piix4 nvme_core xhci_pci_renesas wmi video hid
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  CPU: 2 PID: 810 Comm: wpa_supplicant Tainted: G           O      5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  Hardware name: HONOR BMH-WCX9/BMH-WCX9-PCB, BIOS 1.11 03/31/2022
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RIP: 0010:__sta_info_destroy_part2+0x172/0x1a0 [mac80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  Code: e9 f3 8a 9b fa 0f 0b e9 2e ff ff ff 45 31 c0 b9 01 00 00 00 4c 89 e2 48 89 de 4c 89 ef e8 d6 92 ff ff 85 c0 0f 84 2d ff ff ff <0f> 0b e9 26 ff ff ff be 03 00 00 00 4c 89 e7 e8 6a e6 ff ff 85 c0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RSP: 0018:ffff9d1400bd7780 EFLAGS: 00010282
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RAX: 00000000ffffff94 RBX: ffff8df3866f8980 RCX: 000000000020001c
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000000000020001c RDI: ffff8df384e73c48
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RBP: ffff9d1400bd77a0 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 0000000000000000
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff8df3866f9a00 R12: ffff8df38eb47000
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  R13: ffff8df384e70820 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff8df3866f8980
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  FS:  00007fce39aef800(0000) GS:ffff8df67e680000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  CR2: 00007fa71df76000 CR3: 0000000107aba000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  Call Trace:
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   <TASK>
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   __sta_info_flush+0x12e/0x180 [mac80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ieee80211_set_disassoc+0x152/0x540 [mac80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ieee80211_mgd_deauth+0x127/0x3b0 [mac80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? validate_nla+0x467/0x710
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? hrtimer_try_to_cancel.part.0+0x54/0xe0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ieee80211_deauth+0x18/0x20 [mac80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   cfg80211_mlme_deauth+0xb5/0x1c0 [cfg80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   nl80211_deauthenticate+0xe6/0x130 [cfg80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   genl_family_rcv_msg_doit+0xe7/0x150
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   genl_rcv_msg+0xe2/0x1f0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? nl80211_disassociate+0x130/0x130 [cfg80211]
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? genl_get_cmd+0xe0/0xe0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   netlink_rcv_skb+0x56/0x100
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   genl_rcv+0x29/0x40
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   netlink_unicast+0x223/0x340
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   netlink_sendmsg+0x24b/0x4c0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   sock_sendmsg+0x69/0x70
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ____sys_sendmsg+0x252/0x290
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? import_iovec+0x31/0x40
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? sendmsg_copy_msghdr+0x7f/0xa0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ___sys_sendmsg+0x81/0xc0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? unix_ioctl+0x168/0x1e0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? __cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? begin_current_label_crit_section+0x2a/0xd0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? __cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? aa_sk_perm+0x43/0x1c0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? _copy_from_user+0x2e/0x70
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? netlink_setsockopt+0x345/0x440
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   __sys_sendmsg+0x62/0xc0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1d/0x30
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   do_syscall_64+0x5c/0xc0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? __x64_sys_getsockopt+0x1f/0x30
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x61/0xcb
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RIP: 0033:0x7fce39f6db17
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  Code: 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b9 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89 74 24 10
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RSP: 002b:00007fff30992988 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000555b62049d50 RCX: 00007fce39f6db17
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fff309929c0 RDI: 0000000000000009
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  RBP: 0000555b6204b110 R08: 0000000000000004 R09: 0000555b6214bc10
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  R10: 00007fff30992aa0 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000555b62136b00
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  R13: 00007fff309929c0 R14: 0000555b61541260 R15: 0000000000000000
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel   </TASK>
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ---[ end trace b293ac2b83db3ba8 ]---
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to send WMI_VDEV_SET_PARAM_CMDID
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to clear rx_filter for monitor status ring: (-108)
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  PM: pci_pm_suspend(): ath11k_pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x60 [ath11k_pci] returns -108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 returns -108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: PM: failed to suspend async: error -108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: no GSI
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  PM: pci_pm_suspend(): ath11k_pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x60 [ath11k_pci] returns -108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x1b0 returns -108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: PM: failed to suspend async: error -108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: no GSI
13.02.2023 13:32    systemd-sleep   Failed to put system to sleep. System resumed again: Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
13.02.2023 13:32    systemd systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
13.02.2023 13:32    systemd Failed to start System Suspend.
13.02.2023 13:32    systemd Dependency failed for Suspend.
13.02.2023 13:32    NetworkManager  <warn>  [1676266336.7998] platform-linux: do-change-link[2]: failure changing link: failure 108 (Невозможно отправить данные после выключения конечной точки передачи)
13.02.2023 13:32    wpa_supplicant  Could not set interface wlp1s0 flags (UP): Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
13.02.2023 13:32    wpa_supplicant  nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlp1s0' UP
13.02.2023 13:32    wpa_supplicant  Could not set interface wlp1s0 flags (UP): Cannot send after transport endpoint shutdown
13.02.2023 13:32    wpa_supplicant  WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlp1s0' UP
13.02.2023 13:32    wpa_supplicant  wlp1s0: Failed to initialize driver interface
13.02.2023 13:32    NetworkManager  <error> [1676266336.8023] device (wlp1s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: GDBus.Error:fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.UnknownError: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: (-108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: (-108
13.02.2023 13:32    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to enable PMF QOS: (-108
```

---

**UPD 16.02.2023:** Solution from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=264268) didn't help

But there were some additional messages in the logs. They appear together with the second message from the 13.02.2023 supplement. And also a lot of times:

```
16.02.2023 13:44    kernel  ath11k_warn: 5 callbacks suppressed
16.02.2023 13:44    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to send WMI_START_SCAN_CMDID
16.02.2023 13:44    kernel  ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to start hw scan: -108
```

A few days ago there was an update that included some fixes for ath11k devices, but it did not help too

I'll try sending a report to launchpad now...

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad by `ubuntu-bug linux`

Comment: @Pilot6 ok, thanks. If the bug happens again, I will try to send a report